# Selecting text slower in word than excel

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

When I select text in word the "feel" of it isn't the same as in any other desktop apps, such as excel or when selecting text on a website.

What I've noticed is that the selection in word appears after I've dragged the cursor, it is a very slight lag but I really notice it when working. Anyone else noticed this and fixed it?

Here's two demonstrations, it's hard to see but should be easier to notice when testing:

Word:
https://gyazo.com/b47f0d16d6e9e8e2b16212b932b2ebb8

Excel:
https://gyazo.com/293051aaf4784a71b81e32305df07615

I've unchecked everything in "Advanced" -> "Editing options" except for "Typing replaces selected text", "Allow text to be dragged and dropped" and "Use CTRL + Click to follow hyperlink".

So "Smart Cursoring", "When selecting, automatically select entire word" is already disabled.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like lag to me, just that Word is snapping selection to a whole word whereas Excel is allowing selection of portions of words.

Comment: A simpler comparison is selection in Word vs. selection in Notepad. Here, selection in notepad *appears* much quicker (i.e. just my subjective opinion), but that isn't surprising, because Word has to do a lot more stuff than a really simple app like Notepad - e.g. Word has to deal wtih line and paragraph layout, stuff in all sorts of constructs such as typeface changes, point size changes, character positioning, inline graphics, and things such as Word field code results, display of text in content controls and so on.

Comment: @SamForbis it's not selecting the entire word, I've disabled that, but I also see that it looks that way.

Comment: @yokki exactly, I was hoping it would be possible to disable some of the things that slows down word, making it more like notepad. Google Docs for example doesn't have this problem, but it's online only unfortunately.

Comment: Switching to draft view is about the only simple thing I can think of that might make a substantial difference - and of course if you need to deal with layout/floating objects etc. You have to consider the time taken to switch from one to the other.

Comment: @yokki still slow unfortunately, perhaps I need to look for other alternatives then

Comment: Probably worth trying Word in safe mode (use the command line to run winword.exe /safe and/or make sure no admins are loaded automatically ( /a on the command line of safe mode doesn’t already do that). If that has no positive effect then I doubt there is much else you can do.

Comment: @yokki switched to Libre office now for both word and excel, so much better feel :-)

Comment: Sounds like a result :-)